# XSL changing context node inside foreach loop

Tags: xml, loops, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following xml:

```
<project>
  <workitem id="x1640" linecount="2">
    <texts>
      <text language="en" >English text in one line</text>
      <text language="fr" >German text in <newline/>two lines</text>
      <text language="de" >French text in <newline/>two lines</text>
    </texts>
  </workitem>
  <workitem id="x1640" linecount="2">
  </workitem>
</project>
```

I need to transform it into the following.
For each line in a `text` I need to create a new `textitem` element, like this:

```
<root>
  <textitem id="x1640-1">
    <en>English text in one line</text>
    <fr>German text in</fr>
    <de>French text in</de>
  </textitem>
  <textitem id="x1640-2">
    <en></en>
    <fr>two lines</fr>
    <de>two lines</de>
  </textitem>
</root>
```

So my idea was to iterate over `linecount` like this in a faked for-loop, but with that I am loosing the context node. Is there any chance to get the context inside `foreach` back to `workitem`? Or do I need a complete different approach? Any suggestions would be great, thank you!

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="project/workitem" />
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="workitem">
    <xsl:variable name="lines" select="1"/>
        <!--
    <xsl:for-each select="1 to ./@linecount">   
        -->
        <textitem>
            <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="concat(@id,'-',$lines)" /></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="texts/text" >
                <xsl:with-param name="linecount" select="$lines" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </textitem>
        <!--
    </xsl:for-each>
        -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text">
    <xsl:param name="linecount"/>
    <xsl:variable name="lang" select="@language" />
    <xsl:element name="{$lang}">
        <xsl:value-of select="./text()[count(preceding-sibling::newline)=($linecount - 1)]" />
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: If you declare `<xsl:variable name="workitem" select="."/>` before the `for-each` you certainly will have access to the variable `$workitem` inside of the `for-each`. I would then suggest to use or pass the context item of the `for-each`, i.e. the line number, on and simply use `text()[$line-nr]` to select the appropriate text nodes.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: This is exactly what I need, thank you very much. Why didn't I think of that myself?  :-) If your comment were an answer, I could accept it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare `<xsl:variable name="workitem" select="."/>` before the `for-each` you certainly will have access to the variable `$workitem` inside of the `for-each`. I would then suggest to use or pass the context item of the for-each, i.e. the line number, on and use `text()[$line-nr]` to select the appropriate text nodes.